# R Parsing error when trying to import JSON to R

Tags: r, jsonlite

I've got a JSON file that looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/RyJNYwp3)

I am trying to import it into R using the `jsonlite` package.

```
#Load package for import
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON("test.json")
```

But it throws an error

> Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing
> garbage
> ome in at a later time."  }  {      "id": "e5fa37f44557c62ee
> (right here) ------^

I've tried looking at all solutions on stackoverflow, but haven't been able to figure this out.

Any inputs would be very helpful.

Comment: This is not an R problem but your JSON is simply not valid. Check line 15, two curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file you linked contains *two* JSON objects. Perhaps you want an array:

```
[
{
    "id": "71bb8883780bb152e4bb4db976bedc62",
    "metadata": {
        "abc_bad_date": "true",
        "abc_client": "Hydra Corp",
        "abc_doc_id": 1,
        "abc_file": "Hydra Corp 2016.txt",
        "abc_interview_type": "Post Analysis",
        "abc_interviewee_role": "Director Corporate Engineering; Greater Chicago Area; Global Procurement Director Facilities and MRO",
        "abc_interviewer": "Piper Thomas",
        "abc_services_provided": "Food",
        "section": "on_expectations"
    },
    "text": "Gerrit: There were a number ...."
},
{
    "id": "e5fa37f44557c62eef44baafb13128f0",
    "metadata": {
        "abc_bad_date": "true",
        "abc_client": "Hydra Corp",
        "abc_doc_id": 1,
        "abc_file": "Hydra Corp 2016.txt",
        "abc_interview_type": "Post Analysis",
        "abc_interviewee_role": "Director Corporate Engineering; Greater Chicago Area; Global Procurement Director Facilities and MRO",
        "abc_interviewer": "Piper Thomas",
        "abc_services_provided": "Painting",
        "section": "on_relationships"
    },
    "text": "Gerrit: I thought the  ABC ..."
}
]
```

Comment: It was a formatting error, thanks for pointing it out